# Search for used and unused functions

Tags: android, android-studio

Assumptions

- I have an application with a very large number of screens.
- I see the application for the first time so I don't know it

I have a method that connects to the `Web Service` and I don't know if it is actually used.

Is there any way to check (without running the application) whether the method is actually used in the application?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, you can easily find if a method is used or not.

Right click on the method > "Find usage"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is known. I mean the actual use by the application. That another method uses it does not change much. I can search the whole tree and get to the last class with Activity. But I still don't know if this is a used activity

Answer (score 0):

- Put a `breakpoint` on method and start `debugging` to know whether control
  transfers to that method.
- Put `Log` statements inside method to know whether they are executed.
- Not recommended: Use `Toast` messages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you're looking for "dead code", right ?

You can use **Android Lint** then: Analyze > Inspect Code...

In the results, Java part I think, you will find **Declaration redundancy** which will point you the dead code of the project (or the analyzed package)